# Calling a Visual Basic Function from C++

Tags: c++, vb.net, calling-convention

I have a project that contains .cpp files and .vb files. In one of my .vb files, I have a function and I need to call that function in my .cpp file.
i.e.
In .cpp:

```
If (TrueFunction() == true){
}
```

In .vb:

```
Private Function TrueFunction() As Boolean
Return true
End Function
```

If I try to call TrueFunction, it is reported as undefined. I'm not great with either language, so please forgive any mistakes made in my example.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible simply like that. The ways to interop the two would be through COM or a C++/CLI mixed-mode DLL. Expose your VB component through COM and then in C++ you can instantiate the COM object and call this `TrueFunction` method.

See:

- [Walkthrough: Creating COM Objects with Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x66s8zcd.aspx)
- [Exposing .NET Components to COM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3511/Exposing-NET-Components-to-COM)

Comment: This is not true. P/Invoke exists and is not COM.

Comment: Yes, COM is not the only way. A C++/CLI mixed-mode DLL is another way, of course. I edited the answer. But P/Invoke is for calling native code from .NET, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of different options for interop between C++ and VB.NET. None of them involve interop between vb and cpp source code.

Here's a good [getting started guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227606(v=vs.60).aspx).

1. COM interop - [C# examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) but the same applies to VB.NET
2. C style interop (aka p/invoke) - [Again C# examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx)
3. [Create a managed wrapper in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B)